# Extracting and sorting data in python

Tags: python

Looking for help to see if this is easy enough to do using python, i need to extract data from a text file, the data will then be used in excel to view in tables. I need to extract the following data
Test: 
Date   : 
Critical Test Result Value:
Total Value:
Overall Run Time:
ABT:
RPT:
The file contains a large amount of tests, each with the above info to gather.
As fairly new at using python any help/pointers would be great thanks. 
Number of fails:

Comment: All of this is possible to do in Python, however with one caveat - you actually have to learn Python

Comment: You should post your attempts so far

Comment: or maybe an example of your textfile format

Comment: Just starting to learn python but wasnt sure if this would be to complex to do since just starting out.

Comment: Im just starting my attempt but thought i would ask the question in advance so i new if this was going to be to advance to do for someone starting out.

Comment: Not sure how i add an example of my textfile mbieren

Comment: Did you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? In short: if you want to get help, please share as much as possible information. Your code example (even not working) would be also nice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you not provided details, I made some assumptions (some of them are in code comments). Particularly, I assumed text file format (`CSV` with headers, separated with `semicolon`), Excel file format ('old' `XLS` file format).

Your task breaks into next major subtasks:

- Text file reading
- String parsing
- Writing Excel files

I suggest install packages into virtual environment (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) as a best practice in all of your projects.

This code is far from perfect code and should be used as a starting point for your work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Do in command line: pip install xlwt
import xlwt # Assuming you will deal with 'old' XLS files (MS Excel 95, 97, 2000 etc). If you need Excel 2010+ XLSX files, use xlsxwriter. 
# See here for details: http://www.python-excel.org/

delimiter = ';' # Assuming your data in text file are delimited with this delimiter
data_filename = 'data.txt'  # source data filename
xls_filename = f'{data_filename}.xls' # target excel filename

# dealing with excel, see here: https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook() # Create new WorkBook
sh = book.add_sheet('LogReport') # Add sheet named 'LogReport' to WorkBook


# Read data from text file line by line
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        # line now contains our string
        items = line.split(delimiter) # split line on items by specified delimiter
        print(f'items: {items}') # just for debug to see what we've got

        for col_number, item in enumerate(items): # iterate on each item
            print(f'{item}') # just for debug

            # if you need to expand tokens to a separate variables, see: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/
            #test_id, test_date, crit_res_value, total_value, overall_runtime, abt, rpt, *tokens = items

            sh.write(line_number, col_number, item)  # Write text to given cell: column, row
book.save(xls_filename) # save Excel file with desired name
```